# Acess violation writing 0xcdcdcef#, objects within objects

Tags: c++

Hey so I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm not sure why this is not working. I have two classes, let's call them ned and myfile. I need to have two file objects within each ned object. Here is a simplification:

```
class myfile {
  public:
      int nData;
      int nHeaderSize;

  myfile() {
    nData=0;
    nHeaderSize=0;
  }
};

class ned {
  public:
    myfile *pSrc,*pTgt;

  ned() {
   myfile* pSrc = new myfile();
   myfile* pTgt = new myfile();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  ned* nedObj = new ned();
  nedObj->pSrc->nData=5; //Access violation error here
}
```

This is obviously a simplified version but any ideas are appreciated. I can add more code if the problem is not obvious from this small example.

EDIT: Fixed semicolons which I typed wrong when translating to smaller example

Comment: This doesn't compile due to missing semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
ned() {
  myfile* pSrc = new myfile();
  myfile* pTgt = new myfile();
}
```

to

```
ned()
: pSrc(new myfile),
  pTgt(new myfile) {
}
```

Currently, your code does not initialize `nedObj`. Instead, `ned`'s constructor creates two local variables called `pSrc` and `pTgt`. The variables promptly go out of scope, leaking resources.

Answer (score 3):

```
class ned {
  public:
    myfile *pSrc;*pTgt;

  ned() {
   myfile* pSrc = new myfile();
   myfile* pTgt = new myfile();
  }
};
```

should be:

```
class ned {
  public:
    myfile *pSrc;*pTgt;

  ned() {
   this->pSrc = new myfile();
   this->pTgt = new myfile();
  }
};
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after the class definition

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and fixed it for you

```
class myfile {
public:
  int nData;
  int nHeaderSize;

myfile() {
  nData=0;
  nHeaderSize=0;
  }
}; **//missing semicolon here**

class ned {
public:
  myfile *pSrc, *pTgt; **//was myfile *pSrc;*pTgt, needed a coma instead**

ned() {
 myfile* pSrc = new myfile();
 myfile* pTgt = new myfile();
  }
}; //missing semicolon here

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   ned* nedObj = new ned();
   nedObj->pSrc->nData=5; **//Access violation error here**
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the constructor to this:

```
ned() {
 pSrc = new myfile(); // pSrc is an already defined member.
 pTgt = new myfile(); // Same for pTgt.
}
```

If you use `myfile* pSrc`, you are a declaring a new variable that is not the same as the `pSrc` member variable.
Also remember to free the memory:

```
~ned()
{
delete pSrc; 
delete pTgt;
}
```

Comment: Nothing technically wrong with this solution, though the accepted answer of this post is the more generally accepted syntax.